# Simple IME chrome extension doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm a noob to Chrome extensions and thought an easy way to start would be with a simple example, provided by google, with full source code. So I'm trying this:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/input.ime/basic/

My understanding is that when this extension is loaded/live, it will change all keyboard inputs on any web page to ALL CAPS. Yet this doesn't happen, in fact nothing happens.

I'm not posting the source because the link above has the source that I am literally using, not a single char difference.

To load/run my extension I go into chrome://extensions/, then drag the folder containing my extension code onto there. It loads, no errors. I assumed it's "running" -- yet nothing happens when I type keystrokes on various web pages. What am I doing wrong?

My final objective is to get this chrome extension to receive inputs from a barcode scanner, but this simple keyboard capture is a great starting point. If only it would work. If you have ideas on grabbing scanner input (it's sent as simple ascii keystrokes, but really fast), I'd love to hear.

Comment: Are you running this on ChromeOS? Because this API only works there.

Comment: I'm running it in the Chrome browser. It's a Chrome extension. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API description](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime):

> Use the chrome.input.ime API to implement a custom IME **for Chrome OS**.

As such, this will only work on [ChromeOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS) (i.e., on Chromebooks). It will not have any effect running in Chrome on Windows / OS X / Linux.

Comment: Please help, I know that Chrome Extensions can be written for windows. I have some installed. Can you point me to 1 full source code example of a working chrome extension, that works in windows?

Comment: Almost _any_ other [sample extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples)? Very small number of APIs depend on OS. To learn how extensions work, go through the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: So there is no way to capture keyboard inputs in a windows chrome extension?? Hard to believe.

Comment: I already read through the overview. Just looking for a working extension I can use as a starting point, to capture keystrokes.